# How can I convert a "String-Calculation-Row" WITH operand into double?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

Can anybody help me please with a String-Conversion?
This row is for example a String I want to convert:

(This is from user via a Textfield:)
NSString *testString = @"3 + 4 * 5.2 - 6";

And my way at the moment ist that, but the operands changes ...:
double temp = number1 + number2 * number3 - number4;

The result should be a double and the operands have to recognized. The numbers are not the problem at all, but the operands. An operand like "*" or "/" cannot convert into double with doubleValue. Is there a possibility to do that so from a String?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to scan such strings with `NSScanner`.

BTW '+', '-' are called operations not operands. In your case operands are '3', '4' etc.

**UPDATE**

Looks like Dave DeLong ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong ) already solved your problem  with DDMathParser - https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser

Comment: Do you know maybe a short example if I get a "double calculation row"? Nevertheless thanks for the way! :-)

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you’re looking for "evaluation". String conversion is something else.